Can't import Modal from the modal module
I'm trying to use the Modal class from the modal module. I've successfully installed the module using pip:
pip install modal

Python recognizes the modal module, but it doesn't recognize the Modal class when I run the following line:
from modal import Modal

How can I properly import Modal in a Python script?

The Modal class does not exist in the current modal module. I haven't used this package in a while, but I feel like it may have in an older version.
Either way, the correct way to create an instance of the modal client is to use the App class.
import modal
app = modal.App("example-hello-world")

This is right from their hello world example.
Then, every function just uses app for a decorator:
@app.function()
def f(i):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print("hello", i)
    else:
        print("world", i, file=sys.stderr)

    return i * i

(Once again, this is copy paste from the docs)
Modal's docs are really good. I see you have applied the batch-processing tag to your post. After looking at the hello world example, consider looking at the scaling out gide.
I don't know what your specific problem is without any more context, so I can't do much more than guess that these suggestions will be helpful. Once again, modal has really good documentation and examples.
